# How can I determine if there is an event handler attached to a child node?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

[JsFiddle (thanks @Nick Parsons)](https://jsfiddle.net/ohxajLqp/8/)

I have a simple react component defined as such:

```js
export function ClickableContainer({ onClick, children }) {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={(event) => {
        onClick(event);
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sometimes I might want to have other clickable things inside this component:

```js
export function Page() {
  return (
    <ClickableContainer onClick={() => alert("stop poking me")}>
      <div>Ticklish</div>
      <button onClick={() => alert("me like that")}>Please Click</button>
    </ClickableContainer>
  );
}
```

I want to find a way to modify `ClickableContainer` such that clicks on its children don't also register as clicks on the parent element.

Let me make it clear, I am aware I could do:

```js
export function Page() {
  return (
    <ClickableContainer onClick={() => alert("stop poking me")}>
      <div>Ticklish</div>
      <button
        onClick={(event) => {
          event.stopPropagation();
          alert("me like that");
        }}
      >
        Please Click
      </button>
    </ClickableContainer>
  );
}
```

But I DO NOT want to do this. I would rather save the users of my component the cognitive load and handle it inside the parent.

I have tried:

```js
export function ClickableContainer({ onClick, children }) {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={(event) => {
        if (event.eventPhase !== 3) onClick(event);
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But this prevents clicks from registering on the container at all.

I have also tried:

```js
export function ClickableContainer({ onClick, children }) {
  return (
    <div
      onClick={(event) => {
        if (event.currentTarget == event.target) onClick(event);
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But in this case clicking on the "ticklish" `div` will do nothing, when I only want to avoid it for the `buttton`.

It doesn't have to be simple or pretty, is there any way to tell if an event has already been handled by a child component?

Comment: Your examples aren't clear. In some you're passing down children and handlers - in the others you're not. BTW `event.currentTarget == event.target` does work, at least in the example I tested.

Comment: @Andy I was missing a closing bracket at the end of the clickHandler in the all of the ClickableContainer definitions but I'm pretty sure I pass all the props in everywhere. Which are you reffering to specifically

Comment: `event.currentTarget == event.target` - this seems to work as expected? Can you explain a bit more what's not working with this option?

Comment: Working example from your code: https://jsfiddle.net/yvg9hqco/

Comment: @NickParsons I've updated the question and included a forked version of your jsfiddle. I want other elements inside the container to be clickable, just not the ones that have their own event handlers

Comment: @kaan_a I see, thanks for updating. Not too sure, but maybe you could search up through all parents of the originating event target to see if any of them have an `onclick` dom-attribute, eg: https://jsfiddle.net/dkn8afj3/ Let me know if something like that would work (this won't handle events added to refs though via `.addEventListener('click', ...)`, but if the users of your API are doing that, which shouldn't be often, then they can call `e.stopPropagation()` in that case?)